# Webrtc with DTLS 1.3

Tags: java, webrtc, tls1.2, tls1.3, dtls

I'm trying to implement a desktop secure video calling service using WebRTC. As far as I know, it uses DTLS technology, including for establishing an SRTP connection. But the DTLS version 1.2 is used.
How can I force WebRTC to use DTLS version 1.3 instead of 1.2?

[Wireshark package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRwHx.png)
I use wireshark for package capture, and I see 1.2 version.

Client on Windows 11 has enabled TLS 1.3.
Client on Linux has OpenSSL 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL doesn't have DTLS 1.3 support for now afaik:
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/13900

As an additional security level you can consider using end-to-end encryption of WebRTC traffic (Insertable Streams API gives you access to the frames and you can encode/decode them with your own keys). Some code to write, but it looks like an additional benefit of the secure communication app.